# Need Help to shutdown the Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I stuck at this situation (logstash is not being shutdown). See the details below

Setup:-->

Elastic and logstash are hosted on same server. Filebeat is loaded on another server. Filebeat is sending the data to logstash and logstash is sending the data to elastic. Installed these as system service(Ubuntu).

```
Elastisearch Version --> 7.6.2
Logstash version --> 7.7.0
```

I have loaded 2 pipeline with logstash, checked the data is being sent to Elastic. Meanwhile I need to make a update in one of the pipeline, not able to stop(restart) the logstash.

As I checked, *One of the pipeline have some issue and its data is not being forwarded to elastic. Now whenever I am about to shutdown/stop the logstash, it stucks/hang. (Don't know what to say).*

Now what I have tried to shutdown/restart

```
systemctl stop/restart logstash
```

Ouput of logstash service status

```
systemctl status logstash
```

Output

```
● logstash.service - logstash
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Tue 2020-09-15 15:18:17 UTC; 19h ago
 Main PID: 14298 (java)
    Tasks: 40 (limit: 19141)
   CGroup: /system.slice/logstash.service
           └─14298 /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.awt.headless=true 

Sep 15 15:30:26 Server logstash[14298]: [2020-09-15T15:30:26,238][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][pipeline1][8820ca4] retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"security_exception", "reason"=>"action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized
Sep 15 15:30:26 Server logstash[14298]: [2020-09-15T15:30:26,239][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][pipeline1][88a920ca4] retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"security_exception", "reason"=>"action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized
Sep 15 15:30:26 Server logstash[14298]: [2020-09-15T15:30:26,239][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][pipeline1][88a920ca4] retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"security_exception", "reason"=>"action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized
Sep 15 15:30:26 Server logstash[14298]: [2020-09-15T15:30:26,240][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][pipeline1][88531a20ca4] Retrying individual bulk actions that failed or were rejected by the previous bulk request. {:count=>3}
    
Sep 15 15:30:30 Server logstash[14298]: [2020-09-15T15:30:30,894][WARN ][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt] {"inflight_count"=>0, "stalling_threads_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>43, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]<beats", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.0.9-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:197:in `run'"} ["LogStash::Filters::Mutate", {"remove_field"=>["agent", "host"] id"=>"df6bb998587313a3f737f399367d9ac0bbd9a962a64828c64ee0df7680f2f430"}]=>[{"thread_id"=>35, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker0", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"} {"thread_id"=>37, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker1", "current_call"=>"...

Sep 15 15:30:35 Server logstash[14298]: [2020-09-15T15:30:35,911][WARN ][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt] {"inflight_count"=>0, 
"stalling_threads_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>43, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]<beats", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.0.9-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:197:in `run'"} ["LogStash::Filters::Mutate", {"remove_field"=>["agent", "host"] id"=>"df6bb998587313a3f737f399367d9ac0bbd9a962a64828c64ee0df7680f2f430"}]=>[{"thread_id"=>35, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker0", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"} {"thread_id"=>37, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker1", "current_call"=>"...
```

Other method tried:-->

```
pkill -9/-14 PID
```

but no luck.

I know there are some in-flight data which is preventing the logstash to shutdown. I have check this [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/shutdown.html) from elastic but no help.

There is option mentioned allow.unsafe_shutdown and that option i haven't used.

Logstash logs:

```
[2020-09-15T15:30:40,928][WARN ][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt] {"inflight_count"=>0, "stalling_threads_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>43, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]<beats", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.0.9-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:197:in `run'"}], ["LogStash::Filters::Mutate", {"remove_field"=>["agent", "host"], "id"=>"df6bb998587313a3f737f399367d9ac0bbd9a962a64828c64ee0df7680f2f430"}]=>[{"thread_id"=>35, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker0", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>37, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker1", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>39, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker2", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>40, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker3", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}]}}
[2020-09-15T15:30:45,945][WARN ][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt] {"inflight_count"=>0, "stalling_threads_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>43, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]<beats", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.0.9-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:197:in `run'"}], ["LogStash::Filters::Mutate", {"remove_field"=>["agent", "host"], "id"=>"df6bb998587313a3f737f399367d9ac0bbd9a962a64828c64ee0df7680f2f430"}]=>[{"thread_id"=>35, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker0", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>37, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker1", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>39, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker2", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>40, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker3", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}]}}
[2020-09-15T15:30:50,963][WARN ][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt] {"inflight_count"=>0, "stalling_threads_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>43, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]<beats", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.0.9-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:197:in `run'"}], ["LogStash::Filters::Mutate", {"remove_field"=>["agent", "host"], "id"=>"df6bb998587313a3f737f399367d9ac0bbd9a962a64828c64ee0df7680f2f430"}]=>[{"thread_id"=>35, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker0", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>37, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker1", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>39, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker2", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>40, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker3", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}]}}
[2020-09-15T15:30:55,980][WARN ][org.logstash.execution.ShutdownWatcherExt] {"inflight_count"=>0, "stalling_threads_info"=>{"other"=>[{"thread_id"=>43, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]<beats", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-beats-6.0.9-java/lib/logstash/inputs/beats.rb:197:in `run'"}], ["LogStash::Filters::Mutate", {"remove_field"=>["agent", "host"], "id"=>"df6bb998587313a3f737f399367d9ac0bbd9a962a64828c64ee0df7680f2f430"}]=>[{"thread_id"=>35, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker0", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>37, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker1", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>39, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker2", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}, {"thread_id"=>40, "name"=>"[dem_logging_test]>worker3", "current_call"=>"[...]/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/interval.rb:89:in `sleep'"}]}}
```

I want to stop this logstash service, There is log which says dead url, no live connection, in-flight data but right now I want to just shut it down.

Any ideas? and Any ideas how can I avoid it in future.

Many thanks

Comment: `kill -9 14298` should do the work... otherwise reboot?

Comment: No. This also doesn't work. just want to avoid rebooting.